# Excel 2010 List Synchronization with SharePoint 2010: Bug in the row 20

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2010, microsoft-sync-framework, vba

in fact I have installed the plugin for the synchronization from Excel 2010 to SharePoint 2010. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9345

It works well, however, when the list table in excel has more than 20 items, I have a problem with the row 20, like that the ID changes if I write or edit the row 20. And that results some excessive rows synchronized in SharePoint. Weird..  In fact it seems that someone else had the same problem before
http://www.softfluent.com/Forums/sharepoint-list-synchronizer/list-synchroniser-problem-with-greater-than-20-rows

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't found an explaination for this, maybe it's some problem in the setting up MS. The MS codes are all protected so I have no way to confirm this.

However, I have found an alternative way to this. This bug occurs only in the Excel **Row 21**.

So we could create a table from Row 25 (which is bigger than 21), then there is no bug when we do the synchronization. For all the items are **out of ROW 21**.